# Html.ActionLink is showing the url of the page i'm already in .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I recently made a migration from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET Core 2.2 and everything went well except this thing with the @Html.ActionLink

I've 2 @Html.ActionLink in my _LoginPartial.cshtml, one who go on the Register page (who I did by myself) and one who go on the Login page (who got created by Microsoft with Identity stuff).

If I click on "Register", everything is ok and it bring me to the Register page from the Register controller.
But I click on "Login", it keeps me on the same page I am and the url is also the page I'm already in.
If I browse manually, I can reach the login page.
I guess is something with my routing but I did not change anything in it so I'm kinda lost!

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ml-auto mt-1">
    <li class="nav-item" id="Register" style="padding-right:20px;">
        @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Index", "Register", null, new { @style = "color:white" })
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="Login">
        @Html.ActionLink("Login", "/Account/Login", "Identity", null, new { @style = "color:white" })
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="Login">
        @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Account", "Identity", null, new { @style = "color:white" })
    </li>
</ul>







  app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your code.
Basically: 
ActionLink takes these 3 first parameters:
`string: Text`
`string: ActionName`
`string: ControllerName`
[HtmlHelper.ActionLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper.actionlink?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
In your first link, you are referring to the index page, and the controller name is Register. It doesn't sound right !

Then you have two action links which is suppose to lead to the same page but there is a mistake, you wrote `/Account/Login` which isn't an **Action Name**. It looks like a **route** !

```
<li class="nav-item" id="Login">
        @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", null, new { @style = "color:white" })
</li>
```

Instead of `/Account/Login`, it'll be `Login`. And the controller name I think is `Account`
I think you made the same mistake in all your action links, so be sure to correct the action names and controllers names.

Comment: For the Register part, I have a controller who's called Register and it has to go to the Index method of this controller, so it's correct.
For the Login part, I'm trying to reach the Identity login given by Microsoft. It was working before, that's what I don't get. You see 2 different ActionLink with Login, it's only because I've made some tests :-)

Comment: It's better to name things right to make it easier for modifying/reading, but not the problem. What's your controller name for login ?

Comment: Its Login from Identity/Account/

Comment: Identity is an API, The controller name should be Account ?

Comment: No I dont think so. This is the url i'm trying to reach : https://localhost:44338/Identity/Account/Login

Comment: When using ActionLinks, you write the name of the controller, not the route! So just pass the controller name as a parameter along with the action name.

Comment: Well the controller's name is Identity and the action's name is /Account/Login

Comment: You can't have a slash in the action name. It's not allowed!

Comment: Well it was working before. It still work on the website who's in production : http://register.jak.solutions/

Comment: <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a> --> this work